# Update Jtable values to MySql table

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, netbeans-7

I want to update MySql by using jtable data. I have 6 columns(periods,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri) in mysql. In jtable I have the same table as in mysql. In mysql I have already given periods values(1,2,3,4).

```
Connection con = Driver.connect();
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   for(int j=1;j<=4;j++){
     Handler.setData(con, "update sem1 set mon='"+jTable1.getValueAt(i, 1)+"' where
     periods='"+j+"'" );
     Handler.setData(con, "update sem1 set tue='"+jTable1.getValueAt(i, 2)+"' where
     periods='"+j+"'" );
     Handler.setData(con, "update sem1 set wed='"+jTable1.getValueAt(i, 3)+"' where
     periods='"+j+"'" );
     Handler.setData(con, "update sem1 set thu='"+jTable1.getValueAt(i, 4)+"' where
     periods='"+j+"'" );
     Handler.setData(con, "update sem1 set Fri='"+jTable1.getValueAt(i, 5)+"' where
     periods='"+j+"'" );
     }
   }
```

[image: This is the jTable]

[image: This is the MySql table.It should be the same as jTable]

Comment: I want my jTable and MySql data the same.

Answer (score 2):

- please to read [Oracle Tutorial about JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html),
- table in databases has the similair structure as JTable in Swing,
- (no idea about code before) each of loops inside ResultSet returns only one row, with the same order as is defined in SQL Query,
- create array fills data from database row and add this arraya as a [new row to the XxxTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)
- search for `ResultSetTableModel` or `TableFromDatabase`

Answer (score 0):

This Code should work for all tables(No matter how many rows or columns jTable has). Just Replace 'TableName' with the table you wish to update in mysql.

Here 'No' is a Primary Key of the table.

```
DefaultTableModel dtm01 = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

        String sd0 = null;
        for (int i = 1; i < dtm01.getColumnCount(); i++) {

            //  System.out.println(dtm01.getColumnName(1));
            for (int j = 0; j < dtm01.getRowCount(); j++) {
                try {
                    sd0 = dtm01.getValueAt(j, i).toString();

                    String sql = "update TableName set "+dtm01.getColumnName(i)+"='"+sd0+"' where No='"+dtm01.getValueAt(j, 0).toString()+"'";

                    pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
                    pst.execute();
                    System.out.println(sql);
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    // Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            }

        }
```